# How to extract value between parentheses where before there is a specific string with AWK

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, perl

Im able to capture all values between parentheses with awk expression

```
'NR>1{print $1}' RS='(' FS=')'
```

But im struggling to match one in specific, where i do not want to match by line number but by a string. Not sure if that is possible with awk.

Original file content is

```
if ($remote_addr ~ ^(1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8)$) {
    set $maintenance off;
}

if ($maintenance = on) {
    return 503;
}
```

where there are multiple parentheses in different orders.

I need to extract content `1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8` from the line

```
if ($remote_addr ~ ^
```

(or simply in the line that contains `$remote_addr`).

Comment: So, what is the criterion that a line is a "match"? Is it the `if` statement? Also, do ou want to extract everything in the `if ( ... )` parentheses, or again a substring of that? You stated you want the `1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8` in case of the `if ($remove_addr ~ ... )` line, but what about the `if ($maintenance = ...)` line?

Comment: need that line "if ($remove_addr ~ (MYCONTENT) )"

Comment: You should include some lines that contain `$remote_addr` in other contexts in your sample input/output as it's always trivial to match the lines you want but much harder to not match similar lines you don't want (e.g. `.*` will match any line but is rarely the right answer). For example, add lines like `$remote_addr = 1.2.3.4` and `if ( ($remote_addr ~ ^(1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8)$) && (whatever) ) {...}` and `if ( (whatever) && ($remote_addr ~ ^(1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8)$) ) {...}` to provide more useful  test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you want to extract the content of the *inner* parentheses of the `if ($remote_addr ~ ( ... ) )` statement, the following `awk` program should to:

```
awk 'index($0,"$remote_addr"){sub(/^.*\(/,"");sub(/\).+$/,"");print}' inputfile
```

This will match the line that contains the string `$remote_addr`. In that line, it will remove everything from the start-of-line up to the last `(`, and everything from the first `)` to the end-of-line. It then prints the remaining value on the line.

Comment: That would print a line that contained `$remote_addr` in a different context than the one desired, , e.g. one with no parens such as `$remote_addr = 1.2.3.4`, and would print the whole line in that case.

Comment: It'd also produce the wrong output (`whatever`) from a line like `if ( ($remote_addr ~ ^(1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8)$) && (whatever) )`

Comment: @EdMorton That is true. Alas, we can only work with the examples the OP provides ... :)

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a simple substitution on a single line I'd just use sed for that:

```bsh
$ sed -n 's/.*$remote_addr[^(]*(\([^)]*\).*/\1/p' file
1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8
```

If you really want to use awk though, then you can do this with any awk:

```bsh
$ awk 'sub(/.*\$remote_addr[^(]*\(/,"") && sub(/).*/,"")' file
1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8
```

Comment: `sub() && sub()`, surprising!, vote+

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this `sed`

```
sed -En '/\$remote_addr/ s/.*\(([0-9.]*\|[0-9.]*)\).*/\1/p' $file
```

It will match any line with `$remote_addr` then extract the match.

The code *should* be able to match the pattern without explicitly matching `$remote_addr` beforehand.

```
sed -En 's/.*\(([0-9.]*\|[0-9.]*)\).*/\1/p' $file
```

**Output**

```
1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8
```

Answer (score -3):

```
awk '/\$remote_addr/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /\([0-9].*|[0-9].*\)/){print $i}}}' filename|awk -F "(" '{gsub(/\).*/,"",$2);print $2}
```

output

```
1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).